# Connecting youview box via a D-Link DIR-655 to broadband

Tags: networking, router, tv, broadband, hub

Hope this is the right forum to ask this question:

I have a recently installed youview box with BT Infinity broadband.  I would like to use an old D-Link DIR-655 to connect from the TV broadband cable to the youview box.  The reason is so I can use the ports on the DIR-655 to connect off to my TV PC and other devices that I'd rather not connect wirelessly.  The actual BT Home Hun is in a different room.

When I connect the ethernet cable via the DIR-655 I cannot seem to be able to get the BT Sport and the other channels that come from the broadband cable (rather than the RF aerial).

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will be, by default, trying to supply DHCP addresses to any connected equipment - which will fight your main BT router. It will also most likely be trying to use the same default IP address as the BT.

This contains some guesswork as my D-Link is slightly different, but the principle ought to be the same.

Try connecting a single 'test' computer to it. Shut down the computer, power off the D-Link, connect only that one machine to the D-Link, then power-up the D-Link, wait 2 minutes, then boot the 'test' machine.
Using a browser, go to `http://192.168.0.1` & enter the name & password - default is admin / [nothing]. Change it later if it's still at default.

Then go to setup/LAN setup & disable DHCP Server. Set the Router address to something on your current BT network, which will most likely be `192.168.0.something`, so `192.168.0.252` ought to be a safe bet. Remember that number, write it on a sticker underneath the D-Link, that's how you will access it in future.
Go to Setup > Internet Setup > Manual & check 'Enable Access Point Mode'
You may need to reboot the D-Link at some point in all this, it will tell you if so.

Power-off the D-Link, & shut down the test computer. Reconnect everything as before.
Power-cycle your BT router & any other computers in the house. Power up your 'test computer'.

Uncross your fingers.
 - you should now be able to use the D-Link as a 'through box' (Ethernet Switch) between your BT router & any other devices.

Go back to `192.168.0.252` & change the password, if you didn't already. You might also want to configure or even switch off the D-Link's wifi at this point.

You can get the manual for the D-Link from http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Consumer_Products/DIR/DIR%20655/Manuels/DIR655B1manual070312v23pdf.pdf

**Don't use any of the setup wizards - they will try to set it back up as your main router again.**

Comment: Hi Tetsujin, thanks for the comprehensive response.  Sounds like it will work.  Just struggling with the subnet mask, gateway address and the DNS address.  I've chosen the option to provide a fixed IP address rather than DHCP, but stuck at this point.  As you can tell I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: assuming this is the default on the BT - you can check from another machine on the current BT network, click the Network icon, bottom right (assuming Win7, not sure on 8) Open Network & Sharing, then Change Adapter Settings, then Details - the IPv4 details should give default gateway as  192.168.0.1, if not modify everything I say to what it *does* say; then in the D-Link, Default Gateway & DNS is the same as that, subnet is same (always for home net) 255.255.255.0 These are fairly standard settings for a home net.

Comment: Hey, thanks again.  Still could not get it to work.  I may try it again tomorrow - seems like I'm almost there, but after I change the IP address from DHCP to static it seems as though it does not stay changed.  It reboots the D-Link, but the ip address goes back to 192.168.0.1.  Cheers

Comment: The last step "Go to Setup > Internet Setup > Manual & check 'Enable Access Point Mode'" might need to be done before it will stick.  The entire purpose is to stop the D-Link having any control; it's been so long since I set up mine in this way that I don't recall the precise running order.